# Updating Craft 3 from RC3 to RC4 through Composer

Tags: craft3, updating, composer

I have a problem when updating with Composer.

My installation command line was this one:

```
php composer.phar create-project -s RC craftcms/craft $HOME/craft
```

As such, I tried to update, as per Ryan from Mijingo instructions:

```
php composer.phar update craftcms/craft
```

But I ended up with the following error:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/me
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I checked, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are in the `craft` directory, as expected.

After looking through Composer `man` page and web docs, I am still clueless, as I haven't found what `-s RC` are used for in the installation command. I believe understanding these (this?) switches is probably the key, but I rather ask here than making a mistake and blowing the otherwise perfectly working install. ^^

As for the CP, it doesn't work either, but that is not a surprise given the command line didn't and that I am using the `php composer.phar` method rather than the sole `composer` one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `composer update` in your `craft` directory where your `composer.json` file is? You can install it with `php composer.phar create-project -s RC craftcms/craft $HOME/craft` but you should still be able to update with the normal composer. Are there certain reasons why you don't want to do it?

Comment: Because when I run 'php composer.phar' from the 'craft' directory, I get this:

    Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: That's why you should do `composer update` not `php composer.phar`

Comment: 'composer: command not found'

Comment: Then - if you don't mind - installing the required package might be a good idea. If you have Windows https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows click on the download link and install it. Do you have a valid composer.json in your craft directory?

Comment: Progress: '-s RC' is just telling what source using during project installation: '-s' is for telling Composer the source and 'RC' is to point to the Release Candidate branch.

Answer (score 1):

So, not all hosts allow just using `composer` and impose to use `php composer.phar`.

Knowing that, I can now answer my two questions:

1. When installing Craft using `php composer.phar create-project -s RC craftcms/craft $HOME/craft`, the `-s` switch is just telling which branch of the source project to use. Here, `RC` stands for `Release Candidate`. Before that, we had to use `-s BETA` in order to install the betas. Something I didn't knew since I waited for the RC to jump in Craft 3 and start over from Craft 2.
2. When you want to update using `php composer.Phar`, you need to go inside your project folder (where you installed Craft; `craft` for me which means once logged I had to `cd craft`) and then type `php ../composer.phar update`, where `../composer.phar` tells to go looking for Composer from the parent folder.

I am ashamed not having thought of that; I really need to stop overthinking things.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and no need to be ashamed!